# in Christmas spirit

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language

She's been working very hard to get him **in Christmas spirit**.

Is "in Christmas spirit" the grammatical and natural way to say it?

Also, could someone explain to me what it means to be in Christmas spirit?

Comment: ... to get him in **the** Christmas spirit. Please see [**spirit**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/spirit): **2** The prevailing or typical quality, mood, or attitude of a person, group, or period of time.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is fine, although "... **into** the Christmas Spirit" may be better.

Getting into the Christmas Spirit means getting into the mood to enjoy Christmas. For some people that may be celebrating the birth of Christ, for some people it means the gathering of family and friends and for some it just means a holiday from work.

Other words are often used with "spirit" to indicate getting into the (normally) happy mood for the occasion. Examples include "getting into the party spirit" or "getting into the holiday spirit".

An alternative phrasing would be "... Christmas Mood" or "... holiday mood" etc.

Comment: The Christmas Spirit also includes generosity: giving gifts, greeting strangers and friends with "Happy Christmas" when you meet them on the street and, for many people, giving to or helping less fortunate members of society. Of course some people just see Christmas as an opportunity to eat and drink to excess.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica Good points, thank you. I would be happy for you to edit that into the answer.

Comment: *Getting into the party spirit* is BrE only.  I have never heard it in the U.S.

Comment: The sentence is not fine. "...in Christmas spirit" (without "***the***") is wrong.

Comment: @gotube The sentance is not great, but when spoken it is fine. Minor words are frequently omitted in spoken text, and quite often in written text.

Answer (score 0):

1. ... to get him in **the** Christmas spirit. Please see [spirit](https://www.lexico.com/definition/spirit):
2. The prevailing or typical quality, mood, or attitude of a person, group, or period of time. –
   Weather Vane